# Parse.com : Android how to store Image ParseFile in ParseObject in Offline Mode

Tags: android, parse-platform, offline-caching

parse.com provide a way to save ParseObject in offline mode with object.saveEventually(); call.. this stores object in local dataStore unless the syncing done with server.

The problem is,I can not store Parsefile Like Parse object saveEventully(); method

here is my code:

```
// Locate the image in res > drawable-hdpi
                        Bitmap bitmap = Util.convertBitmap(ImgLocalPath);
                        // Convert it to byte
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                                stream);
                        byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
                        // Create the ParseFile
                        final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("NC_Image",
                                image);

                        // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
                        file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException arg0) {

                                final ParseObject ncImagesObj = new ParseObject("NCImages");


                                ParseObject userObject = ParseObject.createWithoutData("AppUsers", userId);
                                ncImagesObj.put("user", userObject);
                                ncImagesObj.put("comment",obj.getComment());
                                ncImagesObj.put("UserType", UserType);

                                ncImagesObj.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException arg0) {

                                            ncImagesObj.put("image", file);
                                            ncImagesObj.saveInBackground();

                                            System.out
                                                    .println("Images Save....");

                                    }
                                });                                 
                            }
                        }, new ProgressCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void done(Integer arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
```

But this will not work
Only 'NC_Image' ParseObject Create ,but it can not put image ParseFile into that object.

Anyone have solution...
plz help me to find out the solution

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26978612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong its not possible to store/create Parse File in OFFLINE mode,

because Parse File Generate unique object Id of File after Uploading file byte.

That's why it's not possible, But

To solve this problem, I have to store image locally and when network is on after that create Parse File(upload on server) in background.

Thanks for help.. :)