# ParseObject.pinInBackground doesn't work when the object contains a ParseFile

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-datastore

I'm trying to fix this issue for like past 12 hours.

I've finally narrowed down the problem to -
When I use the following code, I'm not able to pin the object. When I run the query later, it returns zero results.

```
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("image.png", byteArray);
file.saveInBackground();
chatObject.put("picture", file);
```

But, when I don't add ParseFile to the chatObject, I'm very well able to pin the object and query it later.

The following is the way I'm pinning the object -

```
chatObject.pinInBackground("unsent", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

I'm pretty sure my code is correct.
Anybody knows how to fix this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pin a ParseObject with a ParseFile to the Parse Local Datastore in OFFLINE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671169/how-to-pin-a-parseobject-with-a-parsefile-to-the-parse-local-datastore-in-offlin)

Comment: ^^ That didn't help.

Comment: But anyways, can you tell me how would I fetch the file back ?

Comment: Hmm. Seemed like a similar problem. I assumed you could save the name of the file and the byte stream in Parse, then just convert the byte string to a file when you needed it

Comment: This way it wouldn't work out with fresco.

Comment: It supports local files and base64 encoded strings also http://frescolib.org/docs/supported-uris.html#_